# Use command line to run Veetle linux application

Tags: command-line

Could someone advise me what the complete command line is to run "sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh".

I've opened command line and used command line hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ run sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh (not working) and hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh (not working).

I guess I am using the command line. Any help?

Comment: It might help to elaborate a bit more on "not working". What happens exactly?

Comment: linux is difficult operating system.. general computer operator cant install the programmes in it ... it must be made more easier for the user.
thanks
installed ubuntu instead of xp and and failed to install veetle now i missed the champions league 10/11 arcenal vs barcelona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you placed the veetle file. If you downloaded it to your desktop, run `cd Desktop` and then run the sh.

EDIT:The veetle script is already an executable. Do not run as root, veetle recommends against it and it will add complications later. (This happened to me)

Sh *is* needed to run the command.

Comment: Hi Zachary...inserted cd downloads (in folder it exists), but no luck.

Comment: Well what is the return script? What does it say when you enter the sh?

Comment: It seems that the command can't find your veetle script the you downloaded. However, sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh is the correct command. Where did you place the veetle script you downloaded from the site?

Comment: The script is in the download directory.

Comment: I clicked on the Veetle downloaded file in the download directory. It executes by just keeps on running with out end.

Comment: You sure than you have tried "sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh" inside of your Downloads directory? Not sure why it wouldn't work then. Type in terminal: "cd Downloads". Be sure of the capital D in Downloads. Then type: "sh veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh" and that should be the end of it.

Comment: Thanks Zachary for your patience...I used the "D"in downloads instead of the "d"...it installed...thanks a million...now I can watch my rugby online!!!!...Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh` with a dot slash `./` at the beginning, or possibly `sudo ./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh` since things are generally installed as root. (Do not put 'run' or 'sh' at the beginning. That is not needed.) You might need to do `chmod a+x veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh` first if it's not already executable.

Comment: Hi...I tried all of the above(3 options) as suggested, with no success.

Comment: hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ ./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh
bash: ./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh: No such file or directory
hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ sudo ./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh
[sudo] password for hylton: 
sudo: ./veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh: command not found
hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ chmod a+x veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh
chmod: cannot access `veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh': No such file or directory
hylton@hylton-laptop:~$ sudo chmod a+x veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh
chmod: cannot access `veetle-0.9.17-linux-install.sh': No such file or directory